# Searching DOM for numbers larger than "x" then appending the number with the difference

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

Completely new to all this so please excuse difficulties with jargon.

Let's say that you have a page with a bunch of years on it. How would you:

1) Navigate the DOM (so far the solution I have come up with is retrieving document.body.textContent)

2) Find the specific strings greater than "x" year (a dynamic variable that changes depending on the context) --> some sort of dynamic regex?

3) Add the difference between the two years at the end of the location where the year was found in the DOM.

E.g. Variable year = 1998

DOM: 
The years are 2012, which is followed by the year 2019, which is then followed by 2040.

Desired end result: 
The years are 2012 (14), which is followed by the year 2019 (21), which is then followed by 2040 (42).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the structure of the document? Is the target year always going to be in the same place? If that's the case, you'd be much better off using something like `.getElementById()` (or similar).

Comment: The target year will not be consistently in the same place. Though, consistently in multiple different paragraphs.